# How to use Async await without assigning to variable? to avoid value that never used

Tags: reactjs

```
   const FetchData = async () => {
     const res = await axios.get(
       `http://localhost:3001/posts/${postId}/comments`
     );
     setComments(res.data);
   };
 }, [postId]);
```

I want to used async without assigning in a variable to avoid warning of unused value i want use async like the code below

```
useEffect(() => {
     async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:3001/posts/${postId}/comments`
      );
      setComments(res.data);
    };
  }, [postId]);
```

Comment: you're only declaring the function! who will call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want to create a variable for it you can use this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/posts/${postId}/comments`
    );
    setComments(res.data);
  })();
}, [postId]);
```

but the above code is not so different from this:

```
const apiCall = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3001/posts/${postId}/comments`
  );
  setComments(res.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  apiCall();
}, [postId]);
```

in second you just create a variable and then you have to use that variable otherwise you're not using that function at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.then` instead,

```
     axios.get(
       `http://localhost:3001/posts/${postId}/comments`
     ).then(res => { setComments(res.data) })
```